# How to access google search console API with wordpress? Api Key and OAuth 2.0 method

Tags: php, wordpress, oauth-2.0

I want to do access the google search console api in wordpress.

So far I just tried the requests in the google webmaster tools. My first attempt is just with the API Key:

```
POST https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/[SITEURL]/searchAnalytics/query?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "startDate": "2021-11-16",
  "endDate": "2021-11-18"
}
```

But when using the webmasters tools of google to test that POST request, I get the following error:

```
 "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal. See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication"
...
```

So before I try to translate that api request into wordpress, can I assume that the api Key method will not work? (But for further different API calls I still would be interested how that POST request would look translated into wordpress code)

Do I need Oauth 2.0?

How would the following OAuth POST look translated into wordpress?

```
POST https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/[SITEURL]/searchAnalytics/query HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "startDate": "2021-11-16",
  "endDate": "2021-11-18"
}
```

Also I have a problem with creating the OAuth credentials. When I want to create it in the google developer api, it asks me if the users will be internal or external. The final website will be used by the registered wordpress users. If I try to choose internal it is greyed out because it says "You are no workspace user". For external it says that you might let your application reviewed by google. I am not sure what to do and what is the right choice.

Is there a plugin needed in wordpress for OAuth? Can you give recommendations?